# Meteor Deployment: mupx setup and mupx deploy errors

Tags: linux, meteor, amazon-ec2

Installing Meteor App on Aws EC2 Linux server. 
I am getting errors at the time of mupx setup as well as mupx deploy, as follows.

In mup.json file, When "setupMongo": true, I got this error.

```
**Started TaskList: Setup (linux)**
[52.33.176.16] - Installing Docker
[52.33.176.16] - Installing Docker: SUCCESS
[52.33.176.16] - Setting up Environment
[52.33.176.16] - Setting up Environment: SUCCESS
[52.33.176.16] - Copying MongoDB configuration
**[52.33.176.16] x Copying MongoDB configuration: FAILED
        Received exit code 0 while establishing SFTP session**
```

When I set "setupMongo": false, mupx setup command works fine like this.

```
Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
[52.33.176.16] - Installing Docker
[52.33.176.16] - Installing Docker: SUCCESS
[52.33.176.16] - Setting up Environment
[52.33.176.16] - Setting up Environment: SUCCESS
```

**Question-1:  What must be wrong with mupx setup when "setupMongo": true?**

After mupx setup works fine, I tried mupx deploy command. I got this error.

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file      : settings.json

“ Checkout Kadira!
  It's the best way to monitor performance of your app.
  Visit: https://kadira.io/mup ”

Meteor app path    : /var/www/html/meteor/test
Using buildOptions : {}
events.js:161
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn meteor ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1028:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:422:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:143:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:537:3
```

---

Following are important things to know

node version:  v7.6.0
npm version:   v4.1.2

mup.json  file

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "52.33.176.16",
      "username": "root",
      //"password": "password",
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      // WARNING: Keys protected by a passphrase are not supported
      "pem": "~/.ssh/myPrivateKeyFile.pem",
      // Also, for non-standard ssh port use this
      //"sshOptions": { "port" : 49154 },
      // server specific environment variables
      "env": {}
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB on the server. Does not destroy the local MongoDB on future setups
  "setupMongo": false,

  // Application name (no spaces).
  "appName": "test",

  // Location of app (local directory). This can reference '~' as the users home directory.
  // i.e., "app": "~/Meteor/my-app",
  // This is the same as the line below.
  "app": "/var/www/html/meteor/test",

  // Configure environment
  // ROOT_URL must be set to your correct domain (https or http)
  "env": {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://musissive.com"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment.
  // Before mup checks that, it will wait for the number of seconds configured below.
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15,

  // show a progress bar while uploading.
  // Make it false when you deploy using a CI box.
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true
  // Make it false when you deploy using a CI box.
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true
}
```

**Question-2:  What is this erro about? I am trying to put a simple meteor app that is given by meteor as a default app.**

Answer (score 0):

Try `mup` (https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up) instead of `mupx`.
You can use this configuration to deploy:

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '111.111.111.111',
      username: 'root',
      pem: "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa",
      // password:
      // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
      // opts: {
      //     port: 22,
      // },
    }
  },

  meteor: {
    name: 'projectname',
    path: '/home/user/project-dir',
    docker: {
      image:'abernix/meteord:base', // of Meteor 1.4 +
    },
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'http://yourdomain.com/', 
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
    },

    deployCheckWaitTime: 60 //default 10
  },

  mongo: { 
    oplog: true,
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I am going to use mup now.
But, I have a question regarding PEM file. 
When we setup Amazon server, we download a key pair *.pem file to our local machine. Do we need to upload this file to AWS EC2 server at "~/.ssh" location and then give that path in mup file?

Comment: I don't know about AWS EC2.  `pem` is the location of your private key (by default it will be on ~/.ssh folder in ubuntu).  The public key corresponding to this key should be added on your EC2 server.

Comment: I tried mup also on ubuntu server. As noted in below answer, my **mup setup** command is working fine. But **mup deploy** is getting failed.
What might be wrong?? 
Really getting lots of frustration.

Comment: Please update your question with latest `mup.js` file.